# Can't connect to SQL Server in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am trying to connect to an SQL server database in visual studio 2012 but having no luck. I have the following code.

```
var db = Database.Open("anagram_database");
var shows_data = db.Query("SELECT * FROM sorted_words");
```

the database name is correct without any typo's, I am receiving the following error

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I am completely out of my depth with this and don't even know where to start. I cant seem to find anything with googling.

Comment: Does the "anagram_database" parameter follow the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.database.open(v=vs.111).aspx): The name associated with the database to open. name can specify an .sdf or .mdf database file that is in the App_Data folder. (Do not include the file-name extension.) Alternatively, name can specify the name of a connection string in the Web.config file.

Comment: in app_data I have anagram_database.mdf but in web.config I have nothing mentioning a connection string

Comment: If you type %APPDATA% in a Windows Explorer, you can see the file in that folder? Are you running Visual Studio as another user (with a different App_Data folder)?

Comment: typing %APPDATA% into solution explorer shows no results, is this where you meant sorry?

Comment: No, Windows Explorer. Press Windows + E keys. Type %APPDATA% in the address bar and press enter. That will open the App_Data folder.

Comment: The file does not seem to be in this folder

Comment: I've added an answer. Hopefully that will help.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.database.open(v=vs.111).aspx):

> name
>
> Type: System.String
>
> The name associated with the database to open. name can specify an .sdf or .mdf database file that is in the App_Data folder. (Do not include the file-name extension.) Alternatively, name can specify the name of a connection string in the Web.config file.

Here, App_Data means the logged in user's Application Data folder (or actually, the user running the application, which is probably the same). Type `%APPDATA%` in the address field of a Windows Explorer and press enter. The folder that opens is where you should place the `anagram_database.mdf` database file.

Comment: Typing in %APPDATA% did not locate the file however I found the file here

C:\Users\Sherly\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\AnagramFinder\App_Data

Comment: So copy (or move) the file into the %APPDATA% folder.